# Food Timing: Keeping Bacon Warm While Cooking With Bacon Fat Made from Said Bacon

Tags: bacon, timing

**The Situation:**

- Guy decides he wants to make bacon and potato cubes (I can't think of a better term) for breakfast.
- Guy wants to cook potatoes in bacon fat
- Guy cooks bacon and places bacon on paper towels to dry off
- Guy cooks potatoes in left over bacon fat
- By the time potatoes are done (20 mins or so), the bacon is cold :(

What can be done to remedy this? Should I just wrap the bacon in tin-foil? I've yet to fully master "timing" when it comes to cooking two different parts of a meal at the same time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I render off the necessary fat over low heat, then remove the bacon strips, increase the heat, and fry using the rendered fat. When nearly done, I return the bacon to the pan to crisp it before serving.

Of course, you could also just save the grease from one batch to use with the next, thereby ensuring you always have both fresh-cooked bacon and (reasonably-fresh) grease to use without having to produce the former before the latter.

Answer (score 11):

Turn your oven on as low as it will go. Put the cooked bacon in there, it will keep warm.

Comment: This is especially handy if you're making a large breakfast, as you can also use the oven for holding waffles, crepes, sausages, etc. to be removed as-needed.

Comment: You can also wrap the bacon in paper towel and set it in the microwave.This also clears counter space.